# How to follow the DRY principle in a ViewModel?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, dry

In an MVVM application, one can often see the ViewModel of the following kind:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

export default function(entry) {
    return {
        id:                             entry.id,
        title:                          entry.title,
        slug:                           entry.slug,
        category:                       entry.category,
        summary:                        entry.summary,
        content:                        entry.body,
        type:                           entry.type,
        video:                          entry.video,
        duration:                       { 
                                            hours:      entry.duration === null ? null : Math.floor(entry.duration / 60),
                                            minutes:    entry.duration === null ? null : entry.duration % 60
                                        },
        createdAt:                      dayjs(entry.createdAt),
        updatedAt:                      dayjs(entry.updatedAt),
        isHidden:                       entry.isHidden,
        isDeleted:                      entry.isDeleted,
        notes:                          entry.notes.map(item => ({ key: nanoid(), value: item.body })),
        steps:                          entry.steps.map(item => ({ key: nanoid(), value: item.body, image: item.image })),
        keywords:                       entry.keywords.map(item => ({ key: nanoid(), value: item.body })),
        covers:                         entry.covers
    }
}
```

If `entry` is not provided to this function, I would like to return the default (fallback) values. Of course, it's possible to just list them in a separate object and return different objects in different cases:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

export default function(entry) {
    if(entry) {
        return {
            id:                             entry.id,
            type:                           0,
            title:                          entry.title,
            slug:                           entry.slug,
            category:                       entry.category,
            summary:                        entry.summary,
            content:                        entry.body,
            video:                          entry.video,
            duration:                       { 
                                                hours:      entry.duration === null ? null : Math.floor(entry.duration / 60),
                                                minutes:    entry.duration === null ? null : entry.duration % 60
                                            },
            createdAt:                      dayjs(entry.createdAt),
            updatedAt:                      dayjs(entry.updatedAt),
            isHidden:                       entry.isHidden,
            isDeleted:                      entry.isDeleted,
            notes:                          entry.notes.map(item => ({ key: nanoid(), value: item.body })),
            steps:                          entry.steps.map(item => ({ key: nanoid(), value: item.body, image: item.image })),
            keywords:                       entry.keywords.map(item => ({ key: nanoid(), value: item.body })),
            covers:                         entry.covers
        }
    }

    return {
        id:                             null,
        type:                           0,
        title:                          null,
        slug:                           null,
        category:                       null,
        summary:                        null,
        content:                        null,
        type:                           null,
        video:                          null,
        duration:                       { 
                                            hours:      null,
                                            minutes:    null
                                        },
        createdAt:                      dayjs(),
        updatedAt:                      dayjs(),
        isHidden:                       false,
        isDeleted:                      false,
        notes:                          [],
        steps:                          [],
        keywords:                       [],
        covers:                         []
    }
}
```

But this way, I list all the keys two times, which isn't really DRY.

What is the clean way to abide DRY in such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in the sense that you don't repeat the same value of type `{ id, type, title, ... }`.

There is duplication of the keys, but the value of the object is different.

#### Different types

If the return type of your function would be `string | null`, then you would write e.g.:

```
if( typeof entry === 'string' ){
    return entry;
}

return null;
```

That is a consistent return type (`string | null`), but 2 different values of that type. That is not "duplication", i.e. this is "DRY".

**Your** type is `{ id, type, title, ... }`, and you return two different values:

```
{
  id:    1,
  type:  0,
  title: 'first value'
}
```

is a different value than:

```
{
  id:    0,
  type:  0,
  title: null
}
```

So there is no way other than setting the correct value for every individual property of that object.

But what you can do is "generate" or "construct" the values for these individual properties, based on rules which you have to define. So ...

#### "granular" code duplication

If objects become that large, it can make sense to avoid code duplication, so that changes to object structure, if necessary, don't have to be made at too many places.

But on the other hand, objects created that way can become hard to read, so this should be considered carefully.

E.g. an object create in this way can remove a lot duplication, but is very hard to understand:

```
{
  id: 1,
  ...staticProperties(),
  ...flags(),
  duration: createDuration().  
}
```

You'll have to find a good compromise.

#### Static empty object

I assume that you probably also need to create an empty object somewhere else, anyway.
I suggest to create an empty object or an empty-object constructor somewhere once, and use it where needed, e.g.:

```
const emptyObject = {
  id:                             null,
  type:                           0,
  title:                          null,
  // ...
  steps:                          [],
  keywords:                       [],
  covers:                         []
};
```

And use it like this:

```
if(entry) {
  return {
    id:     entry.id,
    type:   0,
    // ...
  };
}

return {
  ...emptyObject,
  createdAt: dayjs(),
  updatedAt: dayjs(),
};

// or:
return createEmptyObject();
```